# SQL: What's wrong with this SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following working query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e124/12

```
SELECT date, time, custom_id, Number
FROM traffic t
WHERE CONCAT(date, ' ', time) BETWEEN '01/06/2014 00:00' AND '01/10/2014 23:00'
AND Number = 
(SELECT MAX(CAST(Number as smallint)) FROM traffic WHERE t.date = date and t.custom_id = custom_id)
ORDER BY date, CAST(Number as smallint) DESC, custom_id
```

but for my needs I changed it to this:

```
SELECT [Trunk group], 
       Start_Date, Start_Time, 
       [Inc Seizure Traffic (TG)(Erl)]
FROM   [tbl_TG_Nte-Pac_pHrs] t
WHERE  CONCAT(Start_Date, ' ', Start_Time) BETWEEN '01/06/2014 00:00' AND '01/10/2014 23:00'
AND    [Inc Seizure Traffic (TG)(Erl)] = 
      (
          SELECT MAX(CAST([Inc Seizure Traffic (TG)(Erl)] as smallint)) 
          FROM   [tbl_TG_Nte-Pac_pHrs] 
          WHERE  t.Start_Date = Start_Date 
          and    t.[Trunk group] = [Trunk group])
ORDER BY Start_Date, 
         CAST([Inc Seizure Traffic (TG)(Erl)] as smallint) DESC, 
         [Trunk group]
```

Microsoft Access is giving me a syntaxis error with this line for some reason:

```
(SELECT MAX(CAST([Inc Seizure Traffic (TG)(Erl)] as smallint)) FROM [tbl_TG_Nte-Pac_pHrs] WHERE t.Start_Date = Start_Date and t.[Trunk group] = [Trunk group])
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: The SQL Fiddle is for SQL Server, but you comment that Access is giving you an issue. What platform are you trying to run the SQL on?

Comment: The original query that you change to the second one do not share the same fields.  In fact where does `[Inc Seizure Traffic (TG)(Erl)]` come from? Is that really a field name?

Comment: The date range you're looking at is conveniently within a single month (if you use American-style formatting) and fortunately your date comparison (the BETWEEN clause) will still work. But that's just happenstance. In general, you shouldn't do string comparisons with dates that aren't in year-month-day format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues with the first condition in your `WHERE` clause:

```sql
CONCAT(Start_Date, ' ', Start_Time) BETWEEN '01/06/2014 00:00' AND '01/10/2014 23:00'
```

The first issue is that Access SQL does not recognize the `CONCAT()` function.  You can use the `&` concatenation operator instead.

```sql
Start_Date & ' ' & Start_Time
```

The second issue is that the `BETWEEN` comparison is evaluating dates as strings.  And this condition is True:

```sql
'01/07/1999' BETWEEN '01/06/2014 00:00' AND '01/10/2014 23:00'
```

If you want to compare those strings as dates, you can do something like this:

```sql
CDate(Start_Date, ' ', Start_Time) BETWEEN #01/06/2014# AND #01/10/2014 23:00#
```

Since `CAST()` is also not supported in Access SQL, subtitute `CInt()` as @mvaraujo suggested.  Other possibilities are `Val()` or `CLng()`.

Comment: Hi @HansUP thanks alot. I was still dealing with `CInt([Inc Seizure Traffic (TG)(Erl)] as smallint)` but it was because I did not deleted the _as smallint_ code. But it's now fully working, again Thanks! :-)

Comment: My solution is cited. BUT, I was blaming the parentheses on the column name, whereas the real problem was in the use of a non supported function.

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly because of the parenthesis in the column name (ie. '(TG)').

I've made some tests and, for your actual needs, you may use 'SELECT MAX(CInt([Inc Seizure Traffic (TG)(Erl))' without syntax errors